# Enviar datos de archivo .php a .php / Enviar datos al a base de datos

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Soy un principiante en cuanto a la creación de páginas web, y actualmente estoy haciendo el registro y logueo de la página-
El caso es que quiero que aparezca un mensaje tipo "Usuario creado correctamente en la página de registro llamada signup.php que ha sido enviado desde un archivo insert.php ya que este archivo es el que inserta los datos a la base de datos
He leído posts sobre este tema, el uso de $_GET, $_POST, $_SESSION, pero la página signup.php no me recoje los datos, para mostrarmelos, y como tengo actualmente el código ni si quiera me inserta los datos a la base de datos.

Edit: Ya logré que aparezca el mensaje en la pantalla, pero ahora lo que pasa es que no se envian datos a la base de datos, por todo lo que he buscado he notado que por lo menos en lo básico se pone todo dentro de un mismo .php, así que lo he hecho así, estaré buscando, pero alguna ayuda por favor es aceptada.
Y el error que me aparece es:
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in /home/vol8_6/epizy.com/epiz_26097493/htdocs/otras/signup.php on line 20

Y con var_dump($sql -> error); Dependiendo de lo que ponsa sale NULL

Por si algo, la página la tengo montada en infinityfree, link por si alguna necesidad: http://alstia.epizy.com/index.php

Error dado, luego de unas correciones:
Y el error quedó así:

El siguiente es el archivo signup.php

```html
<?php

require 'database.php';
$correo=$_POST["correo"];
$contrasena = password_hash($_POST['contrasena'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
$concon = password_hash($_POST['concon'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
$message = '';

session_start();

  if (!empty($_POST['correo']) && !empty($_POST['contrasena'])) {
    $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre, edad, correo, contrasena, concon) VALUES (:nombre, :edad, :correo, :contrasena, :concon)");
        $sql->bindParam(':nombre', $_POST['nombre']);
        $sql->bindParam(':edad', $_POST['edad']);
    $sql->bindParam(':correo', $correo);
    $sql->bindParam(':password', $password);
        $sql->bindParam(':concon', $concon);


        $fin = $sql->execute();
        if ($fin) {
      $message = 'Successfully created new user';
    } else {
      $message = 'Sorry there must have been an issue creating your account';
            var_dump($sql -> error);
    }
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Courgette&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assests/css/style.css">
    <title>Registro Alstia</title>
</head>
<body style= "background: #FFABD8">
    <header class="hls">
        <img src="../assests/imagenes/logoalstia.png" class="imgcorner">
        <a href="../index.php" class="sinc">Pag Inicio</a>
    </header>
    <center>
        <?php if (!empty($message)): ?>
        <p><?= $message; ?> </p>
        <?php endif; ?>
</center>

    <div class="div_register">
        <h1>Regístrate</h1>
        <span>o si ya tienes cuenta <a href="login.php" class="ls">inicia sesión</a></span>
        <form action="signup.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Ingresa tus nombres" class="campos">
            <input type="text" name="edad" placeholder="Edad" class="campos">
            <input type="text" name="correo" placeholder="Ingresa tu correo" class="campos">
            <input type="password" name="contrasena" placeholder="Ingresa una contraseña" class="campos">
            <input type="password" name="concon" placeholder="Confirma tu contraseña" class="campos">
            <input type="submit" value="send" name="send" class="sendbtt">
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Revisando no estas mandando las variables get  en header("Location: signup.php");

Comment: ¿Podría ser de esta manera?

$message='Usuario creado correctamente';
header('Location: signup.php?message='._$POST[$message]);

Y en el signup.php (Archivo donde quiero que llegue la variable)

$message= $_POST['message'];

Comment: header('Location: signup.php?message='.$message);
y donde recibes
$message= $_GET['message'];

Adicionalmente busca tutos sobre variables GET y POST para que tengas mejor idea de lo que puedes realizar

Comment: Bueno, corregí esa parte pero ahora el problema viene que no me inserta los datos, en la base de datos, al quitar el header y añadir una correción simple con un echo, me los envía, pero al poner el header con la variable no me los deja en la base de datos, así que no tengo forma de saber si la variable global está funcionando o no.

Comment: Puedes editar como quedaron los archivos luego de la correccion? por otro lado  que error te da  la Base de datos

Comment: Pues, la corrección en el hilo está hecha, y en cuanto al error de la base de datos simplemente se recarga la página, pero no salta error, y tampoco se insertan los datos

Comment: luego del querry colocas 
var_dump($sql -> error);

debe de saltar algun error

Comment: Disculpa por esta pregunta, pero nose en que lugar me dices que coloque el var_dump($sql -> error);

Comment: debajo de donde la declaras 
$sql=('INSERT.....')
var_dump($sql -> error);

Comment: Quedó así el .php////El error lo dejé en la pregunta principal

 $sql ="INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre, edad, correo, contrasena, concon) VALUES ('$nombre', '$edad', '$correo', '$contrasena', '$concon')";
   var_dump($sql -> error);

   if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    // $message='Usuario creado correctamente';
     //header('Location: signup.php?message='.$message);
      echo "hola";
   } else {
         echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
     // var_dump($sql -> error);
     // header("Location: signup.php");


   }
   mysqli_close($conn);

Comment: Ok pero ta te funciona?

Comment: No, por lo que vi, tengo código php desactualizado con código actualizado
El database lo tengo con PDO, pero estos archivos estan con mysqli, actualizaré y seguiré programando

Y los errores están arriba

Comment: Bueno, hice un edit arriba.

Comment: Saludos. Prueba cambiando `$sql->bindParam(':edad', $_POST['edad']);` por `$sql->bindParam(':edad', inval($_POST['edad']));`; desde luego asumo que el dato no lo recibe vacío o con algo que no sea un numero entero.

Comment: Saludos, muchas gracias, aunque me gustaría saber que hace el inval
Aunque el error lo acabo de encontrar, luego de buscar, ayudas dadas por como has visto, y al final lo último por solucionar era un error de novato

Pero intentaré lo que me dices, muchas gracias
Psdt: el inval me tira error.

De todas formas muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré el error de esta parte, tenía un parámetro mal puesto, ya que ando aprendiendo y viendo videos, etc, puse un parámetro como en el video, jaja. Pero está bien, gracias por la ayuda :D
Dejó el código (El segmento concreto de php donde tenía el error)

```html
$sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre, edad, correo, contrasena, concon) VALUES (:nombre, :edad, :correo, :contrasena, :concon)");
        $sql->bindParam(':nombre', $_POST['nombre']);
        $sql->bindParam(':edad', $_POST['edad']);
    $sql->bindParam(':correo', $correo);
    //El error estaba en la siguiente línea, con los datos :password 
    //y $password
    $sql->bindParam(':contrasena', $contrasena);
        $sql->bindParam(':concon', $concon);
        $fin = $sql->execute();
        if ($fin) {
      $message = 'Usuario creado correctamente';
    } else {
      $message = 'Lo sentimos, ha habido un error al crear la cuenta';
```